# how to add indexed tag in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using Azure Storage Data Lake Gen2.
I'm uploading data using the function below in C#.
However I'm not finding how to add indexed tags.
There is a method to add metadata but metadata are not indexed by Azure Blob Storage.

```
    private async Task UploadFile(DataLakeDirectoryClient directory, string fileName , Stream content)
    {
        DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
        await file.UploadAsync(content);
        PathProperties properties = file.GetProperties();
    }
```

I found this article but it proposes a solution with BlockBlobClient : [Adding Tag to Azure Blob C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73626163/adding-tag-to-azure-blob-c-sharp)
If I try to use the blob api to add tags, I'm hitting the error "Blob API is not yet supported for hierarchical namespace accounts"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I'm hitting the error "Blob API is not yet supported for hierarchical namespace accounts"

The error occurs due to you cannot upload files with indexed tags in azure data lake gen2 accounts. I think it is not possible with hierarchical accounts in the Azure data lake storage, I checked the data lake storage gen2 account in the portal there is no index tag present in the file.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can upload files with index tags in Azure standard storage accounts using C#.

Here is the code to upload files with blob index tags in Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "Your-connecting-string";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            var options = new BlobUploadOptions
            {
                Tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "index", "mytag" }
                }
            };
            using var stream = new FileStream("T1IWZ.txt", FileMode.Open);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("myfile.txt");
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, options);
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded with blob index tag.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
File uploaded with blob index tag.
```

[image]

**Portal:**

The above code is executed and uploaded the file with the blob index tag successfully.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use blob index tags to manage and find data with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-tags)